# How to segregate a vector/variable in two states depending upon percent increase of decrease from its previous value

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr, rolling-computation

Say I have a vector `A` (or a variable `A` in a dataframe say `df`) with following values

```r
A <- c(90L, 100L, 5L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 20L, 25L, 2L, 40L, 16L, 16L, 32L, 51L, 52L)

A
#>  [1]  90 100   5  15  16   2  20  25   2  40  16  16  32  51  52

df <- data.frame(A = A)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Now I want to divide these values into two States say `0` and `1` based on the following criteria

- By default first value will be `0` state.
- If the value has dropped by more than `80%` of its previous value (e.g. in third row from 100 to 5 i.e. 95% drop), its state changes to `1` from `0`.
- Here the difficult part arrives.  All values following this dropped value will remain in `1` state until it rises 50% of that value (100) i.e. 50 again.  It rises above 50 in 14th row. So value in 14th row will be state `0` again
- Since last value is not a decrease by more than 80% of previous value i.e. 51 it will be same state i.e. `0`.

So basically I am trying to get an output like this

```
     A State
1   90     0
2  100     0
3    5     1
4   15     1
5   16     1
6    2     1
7   20     1
8   25     1
9    2     1
10  40     1
11  16     1
12  16     1
13  32     1
14  51     0
15  52     0
```

BaseR or `tidyverse` approach will be doing fine for me.

**Where I am stuck** is actually retrieving the threshold value (100 or 50%) till 14th row as you can see it further drops by 80% again two times, once in row 6th and again row 9th.

One more test case can be

```
     A State
1   90     0
2  100     0
3    5     1
4   15     1
5   16     1
6    2     1
7   20     1
8   25     1
9    2     1
10  40     1
11  16     1
12  16     1
13  32     1
14  51     0
15  52     0
16  60     0
17  10     1
18  20     1
19   5     1
20  30     1
21  31     0
22  50     0
23 100     0
```

Explanation

[image]

---

benchmarking both answers on `df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:100, 100000, T))`

```
Unit: microseconds
       expr      min        lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
 BlueVoxe() 214547.5 271455.60 298551.084 300763.90 309823.3 499692.5   100
      Ben()      4.2      4.85      7.115      5.35      9.8     11.3   100
```

Comment: All drops by 80% have to be considered from the value `100`?

Comment: No! that would've been easy part.  Actually, value will remain in true state till it hasn't overcome the 50% of that value which caused it to drop in that state.  For first time it is 100, second time it is 60.  Other intermediate drops have to be ignored

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anil, perhaps this might be something to help in moving forward. It isn't elegant. You can create a loop checking for changes in values, while tracking prior thresholds.

```
A <- c(90, 100, 5, 15, 16, 2, 20, 25, 2, 40, 16, 16, 32, 
       51, 52, 60, 10, 20, 5, 30, 31, 50, 100)

threshold <- NA
State <- 0

for (i in 2:length(A)) {
  if (State[i-1] == 0) {
    if ((A[i-1] - A[i]) > (.8 * A[i-1])) {
      threshold <- A[i-1]
      State <- c(State, 1)
    } else {
      State <- c(State, 0)
    }
  } else {
    if (A[i] > (.5 * threshold)) { 
      State <- c(State, 0)
    } else {
      State <- c(State, 1)
    }
  }
}

data.frame(A, State)
```

**Output**

```
     A State
1   90     0
2  100     0
3    5     1
4   15     1
5   16     1
6    2     1
7   20     1
8   25     1
9    2     1
10  40     1
11  16     1
12  16     1
13  32     1
14  51     0
15  52     0
16  60     0
17  10     1
18  20     1
19   5     1
20  30     1
21  31     0
22  50     0
23 100     0
```

**Data**

```
A <- c(90, 100, 5, 15, 16, 2, 20, 25, 2, 40, 16, 16, 32, 51, 52, 60, 
10, 20, 5, 30, 31, 50, 100)
```

Comment: I find it very elegant to be able to go for a simple loop when the task makes vectorisation difficult. If execution time is a problem, this loop can easily be migrated to `Rcpp` and will be at least as fast as vectorized solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function using `purrr::accumulate()` that should do the trick:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

A <- c(90L, 100L, 5L, 15L, 16L, 2L, 20L, 25L, 2L, 40L, 16L, 16L, 32L, 51L, 52L)
df <- data.frame(A = A)

trans <- function(x, trigger_0 = 0.5, trigger_1 = -0.8) {
  
  # This variable 'remembers' the last value that switched 
  # the indicator to 1
  compare <- 0
  
  out <- purrr::accumulate(seq_along(x), .init = 0, function(prev_result, i) {
    
    # Initial value should be 0 - this will return .init
    if (i == 1) {
      return(0)
    }
    
    # If previous result is 0 we only need to check that change from
    # prev value is less than `trigger_1`
    if (prev_result == 0) {
      
      # Compute the change from previous value
      change1 <- (x[i] - x[i - 1]) / x[i - 1]
      
      if (change1 < trigger_1) {
        
        # Reset 'compare' to be used in next iterations
        compare <<- x[i - 1]
        return(1)
        
      } else return(0)
      
    }
    
    if (prev_result == 1) {
      
      # Compute change from 'compare'
      change2 <- x[i] / compare
      
      # Return 1 or 0 based on the increase/decrease from 'compare'
      if (change2 > trigger_0) {
        return(0)
      } else return(1)
    }
    
  })
  
  # Remove the leading 0 created by using `init`
  tail(out, -1)
   
}

df %>% 
  mutate(Indicator = trans(A))
#>      A Indicator
#> 1   90         0
#> 2  100         0
#> 3    5         1
#> 4   15         1
#> 5   16         1
#> 6    2         1
#> 7   20         1
#> 8   25         1
#> 9    2         1
#> 10  40         1
#> 11  16         1
#> 12  16         1
#> 13  32         1
#> 14  51         0
#> 15  52         0
```

Comment: Looks very elegant.  I am wondering whether this can be translated to lambda function style as well(?).